# Unexpected SVN error svn: E160013 because of 404 error

Tags: eclipse, svn

I'm running my own SVN repository on `Apache2/mod_dav`

It worked fine until today.

I moved a Java class named `AbstractRepository` into a subdirectory, so now the file is "to be removed".

I tried to commit and I got the following error

```
svn: E160013: '/svnroot/repo/!svn/bc/8/src/main/java/path/to/dao/AbstractRepository.java' path not found: 404 Not Found (https://svn.host.org)
```

I tried to `Update` from Eclipse, or to `Cleanup`. `Team Synchronization` view still shows `AbstractRepository.java` with minus sign arrow. Nothing. Looks like that file doesn't exist for the server. But it does exist! I can view it from my browser!

I'm currently the only developer on this project (using SVN to track changes and retain history)

How can I fix the error?